# extracting a string from a text using regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

i am trying to extract price value 4,50,777/- from a string  "price is 4,50,777/- only".

my code is :

```
string s = textBox1.Text
Match match = Regex.Match(s, "^\b[1-9]*,?[0-9]*,?[0-9]*/?-?\b");
string  price = match.Groups[1].Value.ToString().Trim();           
textBox2.Text = price;
```

but  i am not gettng any value.

Comment: There's no groups in your Regex.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the start of the line anchor, unnecessary word boundaries. Since there is no groups present, you need to refer the index 0 to print all the matched chars.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(s, @"\b[1-9]\d*(?:,[0-9]+)*/?-?");
string  price = match.Groups[0].Value.ToString().Trim();
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fD6qI9/1)